# Bash command to find and cut string

Tags: regex, string, bash, cut

I am genereting txt information with tcpdump. In output there is lots of information which contains  something like that for instance:

```
Cookie: id=8xdza1ud39t459hv5bkth4t9gx71dicp; _ga=GA1.2.1890484279.1447252334; __gfp_64b=64smeVuOU7LSnfV8__mvHUkZFQF4lddYYY2X0c0HYAj.S7; __gads=ID=6ccc5cd620798f1a:T=1451575639:S=ALNI_MYeOVLFzU3qJTBxFq6KrdK10QDVrg; __utma=37331766.1890484279.1447252334.1451770396.1451770396.1; __utmz=37331766.1451770296.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); PHPSESSID=70c71a0c25d7d0425c657cee8f30dc2d; OX_sd=1; OX_plg=swf|shk|pm; _gat=1; _gat_newTracker=1; id=iyybhxg7524r2gcuvpguzvbse18c9c21
```

Is it possible to cut only this info from what i have and send it  to another output? To match above cookie it needs to be a string which  starts with "Cookie" ,ends with "id" atribute and contains "PHPSEESSID".

Comment: Can you show your sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud try something like `grep -E "^Cookie:.*PHPSESSID.* id=[^ ]+$"`.

It matches a line that

- starts (`^`) with Cookie:
- contains  PHPSESSID (`.*PHPSESSID.*`)
- and ends (`$`) with an `id=` field, due the `[^ ]` which prohibits spaces following the `id=`

Answer (score 0):

Use the grep command with there required regex to match